# Can't import Font Awesome icon

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome-5

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faCopy, faQuestionCircle, faQrcode, faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

import AddressList from './components/AddressList';

library.add(faCopy, faQuestionCircle, faQrcode, faGithub);
```

I have this code to import fontawesome icons in App.js in react. I am using the free version.

I get this error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'faGithub' is not exported from
>   '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'.

Now all I can try to understand is that the free version does not have a github icon perhaps? However on their [website](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=github&m=free).

That is filtering for free and github. I see it there now why am I such a noob?

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.6",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.4.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
```

`^ my package.json`

Another quick question, where does font awesome even live in the file tree? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hey so I just ran into the same issue and it drove me nuts for the past hour or so haha. Basically, they've split all the font awesome icons into their own "packages" or something. I think there are four catagories as seen on their website in the side bar when you click on the 'icons' tab. They are `Solid, Regular, Light, and Brands`.

For the GitHub icon, it is in the brands package so all you need to do in order to fix it is install the brand package with yarn or npm and import it.

```
$ yarn add @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Then in the .js component you want to add your icons

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

class Main extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="main">
        <h2> Hello Main! </h2>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

here I included both the coffee icon and the github icon to show two different icons.

This leads me to believe that the following should work for any of the icons in Font Awesome...

```
yarn add @fortawesome/free-[ICON PACKAGE]-svg-icons
```

and then

```
import { [ICON NAME] } from '@fortawesome/free-[ICON PACKAGE]-svg-icons';
```

but I'm not entirely sure. Anyway, hope this helped!

Cheers!

---

**UPDATE:**

For anyone who might stumble upon this similar issue in the future, I would actually suggest using the `react-icons` npm package. It contains large a package of popular icon sources (including FontAwesome) and also features only importing what you need. You can check it out at https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer!
I had finally got around it myself importing it like this:
`import { FaGithub, FaReddit, FaBitcoin, FaSync } from 'react-icons/fa';`

Comment: @ekr990011 I actually didn't know that package existed until just now! Thanks for sharing, I'll definitely take a look into it as it seems that is more like a collection of tons of icons including FontAwesome which would be better for development for sure.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the React Icons library recommendation, as of 2020, i found this react font awesome package prettydifficult to use, and thanx to ur recommendation, the react icons library its very simple, easier to use and has way more icons, hopefully, react font awesome improve their package as the current one is a pain .....

Answer (score 2):

**run this command and import:**

1. npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons **or** yarn add --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons;
2. import { faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
3. import { faCopy, faQuestionCircle, faQrcode } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

**[NB]:** socials icons are named brand icons, so all social icons would be import from **free-brands-svg-icons** and others would import from **free-solid-svg-icons**